# how to convert a price character vector to a numeric vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I state that I am a neophyte.
I have a single column (character) dataframe on which I would like to find the minimum, maximum
and average price. The min () and max () functions also work with a character vector, but the mean
() or median () functions need a numeric vector. I have tried to change the comma with the period
but the problem becomes more complex when I have the prices in the thousands. How can I do?

```
>price
                 Price
    1      1.651
    2   2.229,00
    3   1.899,00
    4   2.160,50
    5   1.709,00
    6   1.723,86
    7   1.770,99
    8   1.774,90
    9   1.949,00
    10  1.764,12
```

This is the dataframe. I thank anyone who wants to help me in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always best to provide code that reproduces your data (`dput(price)` might be helpful here).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `,` with `.`, `.` with empty string and turn the values to numeric.

In base R using `gsub` -

```
df <- transform(df, Price = as.numeric(gsub(',', '.', 
                            gsub('.', '', Price, fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)))

#     Price
#1  1651.00
#2  2229.00
#3  1899.00
#4  2160.50
#5  1709.00
#6  1723.86
#7  1770.99
#8  1774.90
#9  1949.00
#10 1764.12
```

---

You can also use `parse_number` number function from `readr`.

```
library(readr)
df$Price <- parse_number(df$Price, 
             locale = locale(grouping_mark = ".", decimal_mark = ','))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Price = c("1.651", "2.229,00", "1.899,00", "2.160,50", 
"1.709,00", "1.723,86", "1.770,99", "1.774,90", "1.949,00", "1.764,12"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url <- "https://www.shoppydoo.it/prezzi-notebook-mwp72t$2fa.html?src=user_search"

  page <- read_html(url)

   price <- page %>% html_nodes(".price") %>% html_text() %>% data.frame()

   colnames(price) <- "Price"
   price$Price <- gsub("da ", "", price$Price)
   price$Price <-gsub("€", "",  price$Price)
   price$Price <-gsub(".", "",  price$Price
```

)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `chartr` in `base R`

```
df$Price <-  with(df, as.numeric(sub(",", "", chartr('[.,]', '[,.]', df$Price))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Price = c("1.651", "2.229,00", "1.899,00", "2.160,50", 
"1.709,00", "1.723,86", "1.770,99", "1.774,90", "1.949,00", "1.764,12"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```